# modular arithmetic proof question

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have to show that there are no integers x and y satisfying the equation 7$x^2-15y^2=1$.

I don't know from where to start any hints. Thanks

Comment: Simplify the equation by considering it mod $n$ for various choices of $n$ and see if that helps.  For example, I would consider the equation mod $7$ and mod $15$ since they both simplify the equation considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$1=7x^2-15y^2=2x^2\pmod 5\implies x^2=\frac12=3\pmod 5$$

which is impossible as $\;3\;$ isn't a quadratic residue modulo $\;5\;$.

Answer (score 1):

That $3$ isn't a quadratic residue mod $5$ follows from [Euler's criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion):  in this case, $3^{\frac{5-1}2}=9\cong -1\pmod5$.

I.e.  the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac53\right) =-1$.